# left join for groups in r

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have a data frame with rows divided into groups, which I want to join with another, much bigger data frame having mostly similar groups.
However the left join will return all the matches from the right hand side data frame, and I only want to keep 1 - but not the same one for the next member of the same group.

For example:

```
Res <- structure(list(ID.x = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Grp = c(1283L, 
1283L, 1283L, 1283L, 1283L, 1283L), ID.y = c(2338806L, 2365559L, 
2870579L, 3129523L, 3184604L, 3283854L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In this case, element 2 from the left data frame belongs to group 1283, and this group contains 6 rows in the right data frame. The next member from group 1283 will again be matched with the same 6 rows.
I would like for each member of the left data frame to match exactly one member from the right, without replacement - i.e. the matches will not be taken more than once.

Comment: Your logic (*"not the same one for the next member of the same group"*) suggests that this could be a `left_join` followed by significant filtering. Unfortunately, your sample data only has one group, so it's difficult to give you a robust solution. Realizing that `Res` is the result from your left-join, please fill it out some to include other `ID.x` and `Grp` combinations so that we can better advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100 % sure if this is what you are looking for (see r2evans's comment).

Suppose you have two datasets

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                  Grp = rep(c(1283, 3821), each = 5))

#>    ID  Grp
#> 1   1 1283
#> 2   2 1283
#> 3   3 1283
#> 4   4 1283
#> 5   5 1283
#> 6   6 3821
#> 7   7 3821
#> 8   8 3821
#> 9   9 3821
#> 10 10 3821
```

and

```r
df2 <- data.frame(Grp = rep(c(1283, 3821), each = 5),
                  value = sample(1000000L, 10))

#>     Grp  value
#> 1  1283 678800
#> 2  1283  11465
#> 3  1283 452869
#> 4  1283 420348
#> 5  1283 315170
#> 6  3821 879067
#> 7  3821 226712
#> 8  3821 995733
#> 9  3821 121852
#> 10 3821   8437
```

and you only want to "use" each value of df2 once, you could create an auxiliary column used in the joining:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Grp) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% group_by(Grp) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()), by = c("Grp", "rn")) %>% 
  select(-rn)
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   Grp [2]
      ID   Grp  value
   <int> <dbl>  <int>
 1     1  1283 678800
 2     2  1283  11465
 3     3  1283 452869
 4     4  1283 420348
 5     5  1283 315170
 6     6  3821 879067
 7     7  3821 226712
 8     8  3821 995733
 9     9  3821 121852
10    10  3821   8437
```